# How can I continue Terraform's execution if a data source does not find any results?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

This command works perfectly fine for me via the terminal:

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name "/something/i/know/exists" --query "Parameter.Value" --output text
```

Output:

```
subnet-whatIwouldExpect
```

But setting it as a variable inside Terraform has been a different story completely.

(I have been happily using Terraform plan/apply/destroy etc)

```
data "external" "ssm_parameter_value" {
  program = ["bash", "-c", <<-EOF
    result=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/something/i/know/exists" --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)
    echo "{\"result\": \"$result\"}"
  EOF
  ]
}

output "ssm_parameter_result" {
  value = data.external.ssm_parameter_value.result
}
```

When I try **terraform refresh** I get:

```
ssm_parameter_result = tomap({
  "result" = ""
})
```

This is extremely frustrating, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my entire file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.34.0"
    }
  }
  
  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  default_tags {
    tags = local.common_tags
  }
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

# Execute AWS CLI command to get SSM parameter value
data "external" "ssm_parameter_value" {
  program = ["bash", "-c", <<-EOF
    result=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/something/i/know/exists" --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)
    echo "{\"result\": \"$result\"}"
  EOF
  ]
}

output "ssm_parameter_result" {
  value = data.external.ssm_parameter_value.result
}
```

---

EDIT:

I am aware of `data "aws_ssm_parameter" "example" { name = "/A/B/C" }`

However, this fails with ParameterNotFound if it doesn't exist on AWS.

And it does not seem as though this is surpsa

I want to be able to utilise the value of

```
data.external.ssm_parameter_value.result
```

to drive the creation/non-creation of other resources later on:

e.g.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "example" {  
  count = data.external.ssm_parameter_value.result != "" ? 1 : 0
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  security_group_id = data.external.ssm_parameter_value.result["result"]
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.another-sg.id
  
  description = "All Traffic from Lambda"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark explained in his answer you should, when possible, use resource specific data sources. Data sources, however, will always error out if the resource does not exist. An [enhancement request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380) was made years ago to request a change in this behavior, however it was declined.

So in this case however the external `data` source is a valid alternative.

The external data source mandates that the program output must be a JSON object. In this example, you could do:

```
# Execute AWS CLI command to get SSM parameter value
data "external" "ssm_parameter_value" {
  program = ["bash", "-c", <<-EOF
    param=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/something/i/know/exists" --query "Parameter.Value" --output text 2>/dev/null);
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then 
      jq -r -n --arg param "$param" '{"param":$param}'
    else
      jq -r -n '{"param":""}'
    fi
  EOF
  ]
}

output "ssm_parameter_result" {
  value = data.external.ssm_parameter_value.result.param
}
```

If the secret exists, the output will be:

```
$ terraform apply
...
ssm_parameter_result = "foo"
```

If the secret does not exist, the output will be:

```
$ terraform apply
...
ssm_parameter_result = ""
```

Note that this approach requires `jq` for the creation of the JSON object.

Comment: this is a far better comment than Mark's, I appreciate the considerations you made